# How do I write SQL to get a time difference between 2 status in a workflow

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains workflow of applications. These workflows changes from status from status. There are multiple status in a workflow. I want to calculate the time difference between 2 status (without counting the weekends) Here is the sample:

```
appl_id  timestamp                     status                           daydiff
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2016-02-22-14.57.40.000000    application submitted     
1        2016-02-22-15.29.00.000000    under review                      0  
1        2016-03-02-14.00.30.000000    send back to user for correction  6 
1        2016-03-03-08.49.10.000000    under review                      1
1        2016-03-03-09.18.30.000000    approved                          0
1        2016-03-15-14.16.05.000000    waiting for signed contract       8
1        2016-03-17-14.32.08.000000    successfully enrolled             2


2        2016-02-19-11.11.20.000000    application submitted             
2        2016-02-23-11.25.50.000000    under review                      2
2        2016-02-24-15.32.40.000000    approved                          1
2        2016-03-16-14.39.20.000000    waiting for signed contract       15
2        2016-03-17-03.24.00.000000    successfully enrolled             1
```

I can accomplish this by joining the table to itself and subtracting the status from one table to another. But I would like to use just one table to do the calculation so that the subtraction is from one row to the row above.

Thank you in advance for the guidance.

Comment: Look at the `LAG` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OUTER APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
SELECT  y.*,
        ISNULL(DATEDIFF(day,s.[timestamp],y.[timestamp]),0) as daydiff
FROM YourTable y
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE appl_id = y.appl_id and [timestamp] < y.[timestamp] and [status] != y.[status]
    ORDER BY [timestamp] DESC
) s
```

Output:

```
appl_id timestamp                   status                              daydiff
1       2016-02-22 14:57:40.000000  application submitted               0
1       2016-02-22 15:29:00.000000  under review                        0
1       2016-03-02 14:00:30.000000  send back to user for correction    9
1       2016-03-03 08:49:10.000000  under review                        1
1       2016-03-03 09:18:30.000000  approved                            0
1       2016-03-15 14:16:05.000000  waiting for signed contract         12
1       2016-03-17 14:32:08.000000  successfully enrolled               2
2       2016-02-19 11:11:20.000000  application submitted               0
2       2016-02-23 11:25:50.000000  under review                        4
2       2016-02-24 15:32:40.000000  approved                            1
2       2016-03-16 14:39:20.000000  waiting for signed contract         21
2       2016-03-17 03:24:00.000000  successfully enrolled               1
```

Or with [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) (starting with SQL Server 2012) function:

```
SELECT  *,
        DATEDIFF(day,LAG([timestamp],1,[timestamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY appl_id ORDER BY [timestamp]),[timestamp]) as daydiff
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes according to your requirement.

```
Declare @Tab table
(
appl_id INT,
time_stamp datetime,
stat varchar(50)
);

Insert into @Tab values (1, '2016-02-22', 'application submitted');
Insert into @Tab values (1, '2016-02-22', 'under review ');
Insert into @Tab values (1, '2016-03-02', 'send back to user for correction');
Insert into @Tab values (1, '2016-03-03', 'under review');
Insert into @Tab values (1, '2016-03-03', 'approved');
Insert into @Tab values (1, '2016-03-15', 'waiting for signed contract');
Insert into @Tab values (1, '2016-03-17', 'successfully enrolled');

Insert into @Tab values (2, '2016-02-19', 'application submitted');
Insert into @Tab values (2, '2016-02-23', 'under review ');
Insert into @Tab values (2, '2016-02-24', 'approved');
Insert into @Tab values (2, '2016-03-16', 'waiting for signed contract');
Insert into @Tab values (2, '2016-03-17', 'successfully enrolled');

--Add a CASE WHEN to make the default to NULL for [application submitted]
Select appl_id, time_stamp, stat,
PreviousData = LAG(time_stamp, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY appl_id ORDER BY appl_id)
, DayDiffIncWeekdays= ABS(DateDiff(Day, time_stamp, LAG(time_stamp, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY appl_id ORDER BY appl_id)))
, NoOfWeekends = dbo.fnc_NumberOfWeekEnds(LAG(time_stamp, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY appl_id ORDER BY appl_id), time_stamp)
, ActualDayDiff = ABS(DateDiff(Day, time_stamp, LAG(time_stamp, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY appl_id ORDER BY appl_id)))
- dbo.fnc_NumberOfWeekEnds(LAG(time_stamp, 1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY appl_id ORDER BY appl_id), time_stamp)
from @Tab

--Fuction to get number of weekends
CREATE FUNCTION fnc_NumberOfWeekEnds(@dFrom DATETIME, @dTo   DATETIME)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
   Declare @weekends int
   Set @weekends = 0
   While @dFrom <= @dTo Begin
      If ((datepart(dw, @dFrom) = 1) OR (datepart(dw, @dFrom) = 7))  
                  Set @weekends = @weekends + 1
                  Set @dFrom = DateAdd(d, 1, @dFrom)
   End
   Return (@weekends)
END
```